# how to use pandas isin for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to find the values of `col1` and `col2` where the `col1` and `col2` of the first dataframe are both in the second dataframe.

These rows should be in the result dataframe:

1. pizza, boy
2. pizza, girl
3. ice cream, boy

because all three rows are in the first and second dataframes.

How do I possibly accomplish this? I was thinking of using `isin`, but I am not sure how to use it when I have to consider more than one column.

Answer (score 27):

Perform an [inner merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on `col1` and `col2`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'hamburger', 'hamburger', 'pizza', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy']}, index=range(1,6))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'pizza', 'chicken', 'cake', 'cake', 'chicken', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy', 'girl', 'boy', 'boy']}, index=range(10,17))

print(pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), df1, how='inner').set_index('index'))
```

yields

```
            col1  col2
index                 
10         pizza   boy
11         pizza  girl
16     ice cream   boy
```

The purpose of the `reset_index` and `set_index` calls are to preserve `df2`'s index as in the desired result you posted. If the index is not important, then

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner')
#         col1  col2
# 0      pizza   boy
# 1      pizza  girl
# 2  ice cream   boy
```

would suffice.

---

Alternatively, you could construct [`MultiIndex`s](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) out of the `col1` and `col2` columns, and then call the [`MultiIndex.isin` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html):

```
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1[col] for col in ['col1', 'col2']])
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2[col] for col in ['col1', 'col2']])
print(df2.loc[index2.isin(index1)])
```

yields

```
         col1  col2
10      pizza   boy
11      pizza  girl
16  ice cream   boy
```

Comment: Instead of MultiIndex, you could opt to use df.loc[df.isin(filter_to_apply).sum(axis=1)
                == len(filter_to_apply.keys()), :]

Here, filter to apply is a dictionary with column names as key, and dict values a list of values
This takes the row-wise sum of the binary result of df.isin(filter_to_apply), and ensures that we filter rows for which all elements in the row are True. can easily change this filter for other types of filters

Answer (score 12):

Thank you unutbu!
Here is a little update.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'hamburger', 'hamburger', 'pizza', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy']}, index=range(1,6))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'pizza', 'chicken', 'cake', 'cake', 'chicken', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy', 'girl', 'boy', 'boy']}, index=range(10,17))
df1[df1.set_index(['col1','col2']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['col1','col2']).index)]
```

return:

```
    col1    col2
1   pizza   boy
4   pizza   girl
5   ice cream   boy
```

Answer (score 4):

If somehow you must stick to `isin` or the negate version `~isin`.
You may first create a new column, with the concatenation of `col1`, `col2`. Then use `isin` to filter your data. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'hamburger', 'hamburger', 'pizza', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy']}, index=range(1,6))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['pizza', 'pizza', 'chicken', 'cake', 'cake', 'chicken', 'ice cream'], 'col2': ['boy', 'girl', 'girl', 'boy', 'girl', 'boy', 'boy']}, index=range(10,17))

df1['indicator'] = df1['col1'].str.cat(df1['col2'])
df2['indicator'] = df2['col1'].str.cat(df2['col2'])

df2.loc[df2['indicator'].isin(df1['indicator'])].drop(columns=['indicator'])
```

which gives

```
    col1    col2
10  pizza   boy
11  pizza   girl
16  ice cream   boy
```

If you do so remember to make sure that concatenating two columns doesn't create false positives e.g. concatenation of `123` and `456` in `df1` and concatenation of `12` and `3456` in `df2` will match even though their respective columns don't match. You can fix this problem by additional `sep` parameter.

```
df1['indicator'] = df1['col1'].str.cat(df1['col2'], sep='$$$')
df2['indicator'] = df2['col1'].str.cat(df2['col2'], sep='$$$')
```

Comment: would u please elaborate why ```.drop(columns=['indicator']``` are used?

Comment: @CN_Cabbage Because we don't want the temporary helper column to show up in the processed data frame.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to define a check function of your own and perform `apply` on the dataframe.

For example, if you know the list of combinations that need to be filtered (this list can be extracted beforehand from a dataframe):

```
filter_list_multicols = [["book", "cat"], ["table", "dog"], ["table", "cat"], ["pen", "horse"], ["book", "horse"]]
```

Then you could define a check function as so:

```
def isin_multicols_check(stationary_name, animal_name):
    for filter_pair in filter_list_multicols:
        if (stationary_name == filter_pair[0]) and (animal_name == filter_pair[1]):
                return True

    return False
```

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   [1, "book", "dog"], [2, "pen", "dog"], [3, "pen", "rat"], [4, "book", "horse"], [5, "book", "cat"]
                  ],
                   columns=["S.N.", "stationary_name", "animal_name"])
df
```

```
S.N.    stationary_name  animal_name
1           book            dog
2           pen             dog
3           pen             rat
4           book            horse
5           book            cat
```

And now, call the function using pandas `apply`:

```
df["is_in"] = df.apply(lambda x: isin_multicols_check(x.stationary_name, x.animal_name), axis=1)
df
```

```
S.N.    stationary_name  animal_name    is_in
1           book            dog         false
2           pen             dog         false
3           pen             rat         false
4           book            horse       true
5           book            cat         true
```

The result:

```
is_in = df[df["is_in"]==True]
not_is_in = df[df["is_in"]==False]
```