# How to use isin (without merge) for multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

`df1`

```
   Company  Symbol     ID         Date    Value
0  AAA Inc       A    123   2019-12-31       10
1  AAA Inc       A    123   2020-03-30       11
2  BBB Inc       B    456   2019-03-31       12
3  FFF Inc       F    653   2019-06-31       22
4  ZZZ Inc       Z    999   2019-03-30       13
```

`df2`

```
   Company  Symbol     ID         Date   Price
0  AAA Inc       A    123   2019-12-31      10
1  AAA Inc       A    123   2019-09-30      20
2  AAA Inc       A    123   2019-06-31      30
3  AAA Inc       A    123   2019-03-30      40
4  BBB Inc       B    456   2019-12-31      50
5  BBB Inc       B    456   2019-09-30      50
6  BBB Inc       B    456   2019-06-31      90
7  BBB Inc       B    456   2019-03-31      10
8  CCC Inc       C    789   2019-12-31      79
9  CCC Inc       C    789   2019-09-31      43
```

And I want to create a 3rd dataframe which is all the `['Symbol', 'ID', 'Date']` rows that are in `df1`, but not in `df2`. So the output would look like this:

```
   Company  Symbol     ID         Date
0  AAA Inc       A    123   2020-03-30
1  FFF Inc       F    653   2019-06-31
2  ZZZ Inc       Z    999   2019-03-30
```

I know I can do something like `df3 = df1[~df1['Symbol'].isin(df2['Symbol'])]`, but after doing some research it doesn't seem like there's a good way to use `isin` with multiple columns.

I have also checked similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663017/reliable-way-of-dropping-rows-in-df1-which-are-also-in-df2) but haven't found anything that only addresses specific columns.

I would also like to avoid [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198786/how-to-use-pandas-isin-for-multiple-columns) the two dataframes if possible.

So how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Because you want avoid `merge` here is one posible solution is compare `MultiIndex` by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
cols = ['Symbol', 'ID', 'Date']
df3 = df1[~df1.set_index(cols).index.isin(df2.set_index(cols).index)]
print (df3)
  Company Symbol   ID        Date  Value
1     AAA  Inc A  123  2020-03-30     11
3     FFF  Inc F  653  2019-06-31     22
4     ZZZ  Inc Z  999  2019-03-30     13
```

Or convert columns to tuples:

```
cols = ['Symbol', 'ID', 'Date']
df3 = df1[~df1[cols].apply(tuple, 1).isin(df2[cols].apply(tuple, 1))]
```

For compare solution with `merge` and `indicator` parameter:

```
cols = ['Symbol', 'ID', 'Date']
df3 = (df1.merge(df2, on=cols, indicator=True, how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
          .query("_merge == 'left_only'")[df1.columns])
print (df3)
  Company Symbol   ID        Date  Value
1     AAA  Inc A  123  2020-03-30     11
3     FFF  Inc F  653  2019-06-31     22
4     ZZZ  Inc Z  999  2019-03-30     13
```

Comment: Am I making this more difficult for myself by not using merge?

Comment: @MSD - I think it is simplier ;) But if lage both DataFrames not sure if more performant, the best test.

Comment: It's not a very large dataframe so performance isn't a huge concern. So maybe I'll just look at merge then.

Comment: this is a bit longer, and performant????? not sure : ```ind = ['Symbol','ID','Date'];
df1.loc[(~df1.filter(ind).isin(df2.to_dict('list'))).any(axis=1)]```